# Uninstall/Remove tomcat 9 completely from CentOS

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos7, rpm, tomcat9

I am trying to remove tomcat 9 from CentOS completely.

First I used

```
rpm -qa|grep tomcat
```

The output I got was

```
tomcat-9.0.0-26.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Then I used

```
sudo yum remove tomcat.x86_64
```

When I again tried

```
rpm -qa|grep tomcat
```

I didnt get any output.
And I am not sure if the tomcat is removed completely or not.
When I used the following command,

```
sudo yum list|grep -i tomcat
```

I can see a list which is

```
jglobus-ssl-proxies-tomcat.noarch       2.1.0-6.el7                    epel     
tomcat.noarch                           7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-admin-webapps.noarch             7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-docs-webapp.noarch               7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-el-2.2-api.noarch                7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-javadoc.noarch                   7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-jsp-2.2-api.noarch               7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-jsvc.noarch                      7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-lib.noarch                       7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-native.x86_64                    1.1.34-1.el7                   epel     
tomcat-servlet-3.0-api.noarch           7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcat-webapps.noarch                   7.0.76-2.el7                   base     
tomcatjss.noarch                        7.2.1-6.el7                    base
```

So my question is now I am not sure if tomcat is completely removed or not? If it is not, what else should I do to completely remove it from my system?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably gone. `yum list` is showing you all installed *and* available in various repos (in your output, base and epel). `yum list installed` or `rpm -qa` will show you *only* the ones currently installed. (And, for completeness, `yum list available` is the other option.)